# matplotlib resize event defined in main

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying invoke `resize_event` for `matplotlib` as

```
def main():
  sc2 = ax.scatter(Zu, Nu, color=color, s=s)
  cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', on_resize)


def on_resize(event):
  """Callback function on interactive plot window resize."""
  # Resize the scatter plot markers to keep the plot looking good.
  s = get_marker_size(ax, maxZ, maxN)
  sc2.set_sizes([s] * len(Zs))

main()
```

but, I cant transfer the `sc2` defined in `main` to `on_resize`, and I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
||   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 196, in size_allocate
||     FigureCanvasBase.resize_event(self)
||   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1787, in resize_event
||     self.callbacks.process(s, event)
||   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 292, in process
||     self.exception_handler(exc)
||   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 96, in _exception_printer
||     raise exc
||   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 287, in process
||     func(*args, **kwargs)
||   File "/home/rudra/Teaching/Nuclear/Codes/newhalf.py", line 107, in on_resize
||     sc1.set_sizes([s] * (len(Zs + Zu)))
|| NameError: name 'sc1' is not defined
```

Can I do this without definig a `class`?